# Stabilization techniques for mobile builds?

Tags: android, ios, build, mobile-development

**Please note:** although I specifically mention AngularJS, Ionic and Cordova here, I'm really talking about *any* mobile app (hybrid and native alike) that produces binaries for iOS and Android platforms. As such, I believe that anybody with experience in mobile dev should be able to address the question!

---

I am building a mobile app for iOS and Android using AngularJS, Ionic and Cordova. My concern is that iOS and Android release updates all the time, some may be buggy or just might be outright breaking changes and all of the sudden become incompatible with the plugin/library versions that I'm using.

This will cause apps to crash spontaneously in production. But it sheds light on an even nastier problem under the hood: making the decision to pin your builds against specific dependency (plugins/libraries/etc.) versions *or* just always pull in the latest/stable versions of them!

#### Option 1: Pin your dependency versions

Here we specify the exact version of *all* dependencies to use. We then fight with the Ionic build to get the app built, but are now good to go. I can expect that if I don't change any of my code, that each subsequent build of the app against the exact same dependency versions will always result with a successful build.

*However*, when iOS/Android *does* release a breaking change or bug (or anything that prompts the library/plugin maintainers to go into a frenzy and publish new versions of themselves), because I've pinned my previous build to specific versions of dependencies, I may actually be running on very old dependency versions and it will now be a massive headache to get my app building again against all the latest versions.

#### Option 2: Use latest/stable versions at all times

If I *don't* specify dependency versions (and just let the build always use latest and greatest), then I could work fervently to get my app building, then wait a few days (and not change any of my own code) and then try building it again and the compile/build might fail! This is because in between those few days, some project upgraded itself and/or its own dependencies and introduced a build-breaking change.

*However*, when iOS/Android releases a breaking change that requires me to upgrade to latest dependencies, the headache would likely be considerably less then Option 1 since I'll be on a relatively much newer version of all my dependencies.

**Are there any tools/strategies/techniques/etc. that the mobile community leverages to stabilize builds and make it so that I can have more consistent, repeatable builds?**

Comment: Why the DV? This is on topic, shows research and is not a dupe...

Comment: Are you familiar with Continious Integration?

Comment: Thanks @JoeriShoeby, I'm *very* familiar with CI! How do you suggest I leverage CI to solve this problem?

Comment: Also @JoeriShoeby -- I don't think CI is a possible solution for iOS, since iOS *must* compile inside of Xcode which requires Mac hardware. Unless you're suggesting having an on-premise Mac server used for CI purposes...

Comment: Meh, doesn't even look like Macs sell servers anymore. Yeah I'm not seeing how CI would solve this for iOS...

Comment: You don't need a MAC server to do CI using Jenkins. You just need a Mac machine, which will act as Slave for your main Jenkins server( which could be running on Windows). Your mac machine will only build for iOS

In order to achieve build stability, you need to have good coverage of instrumentation and unit test. For Android you can make the targetSdkVersion configurable. Each time Google releases new preview version, you can change this value on CI and run your tests. It allows you to detect issues early and ensure stabilty. Same could be done for iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommend to use specific version of your dependencies, you may consider using the notion * at the minor patch level X.Y.* to get the lastest bug fixes.

Your build should be automatic and consistent, there are products that do this for you, e.g BuddyBuild and Buddy support both Android and IOS.

Successful builds is not the whole thing, The app should pass all the functionality and QA tests before a release. So you need to write as much as UnitTests and FunctionalTest to cover the quality checks. There are other QC tools for even further assurance, For example static code analysis tools help you to discover potential bugs and failures, And test coverage tools let you know which parts of your code has not been tested yet.

Here is a Simple CI/CD workflow

`Code -> Push -> CI Test -> CD Publish Release`

You can set a job to build your project on a weekly basis on the CI server and Publish a Release only if it passes all the Quality Checks

Apps crashing on the new OS versions is not a catastrophic problem, it's common and has its solution, Google and Apple don't release new OS versions to users just like that, Developers are provided with preview builds of the OS and new APIs, Developers usually have more than 2 month to adopt thier apps with the new changes and even use the new API features.

And by the way you have access to crash reporting tools like Fabric.io and Firebase which helps you to discover problems at production.

Cheers

Comment: +1 for the the preview builds suggestion, definitely a gd strategy to catch bugs early on before an official OS update

Comment: Thanks @M.Reza (+1), I like what you are suggesting here, there are two main pushbacks I'm hearing from my mobile developers: **(1)** that while Android/iOS offer a "preview mode" for their new versions, that this doesn't apply when they need to publish emergency fixes/security patches without warning. **Can you speak to how often this happens and how your solution above could accommodate these unannounced/emergency fixes?**

Comment: And **(2)** my mobile developers tell me that once in a while certain platforms tools (especially Xcode) force developers to upgrade to latest dependencies.  **In your experience is this true, and if so how does your above solution handle this?** Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: @smeeb Emergency fixes are usually for security patches, Every big tech company knows if they're introducing breaking changes they have to release it under the major updates, even though it is a minor fix. So It goes through the same process of maunge it available to developers, Even for a short period ahead of public release. And don't get frightened by new releases, the new version won't hit to even 1 percentage of Android users for months, You have less time for IOS though.

Comment: @smeeb (2) It only forces you if you want to build for new OS versions or you have a really old instance.